# How can I insert HTML tags in C# string property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Not sure how if it is possible, but I have this in a class:

```
public string TextNotIncluded 
{ 
    get
    { 
        return ("which is <u>not</u> included in the Quote");
    }
}
```

The `<u>` and `</u>` are being displayed in my view, rather than the word not being underlined. I am not familiar with C#.

Can anyone provide a quick answer?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I am just calling this in my view thusly: `@MyClass.TextNotIncluded`. Wrapping it with `@Html.Raw` is not efficient in my case because I have this sprinkled throughout dozens of views.

Comment: It depends what control you're outputting that string in. I'd guess that whatever you're using does not parse HTML markup.

Comment: show us how you are consuming this property from your MVC view or controller

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with doing that but it probably won't render the way you're expecting.

You can use `@Html.Raw` as others have suggested, but I think it's better to explicitly declare your model in such a way as to indicate that it may contain html. You probably want to use the [`MvcHtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchtmlstring%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class for this instead:

```
public MvcHtmlString TextNotIncluded 
{ 
    get { return MvcHtmlString.Create("which is <u>not</u> included in the Quote"); }
}
```

Then in your view you can just use:

```
@Model.TextNotIncluded
```

Comment: +1 For altering the property's return type, since it is returning html anyway I would vote for a change at the source too.

Comment: As a side-note, this assumes that your model is specific to your MVC project - if your model lives in a DTO or data layer, it wouldn't make sense for a property to be an `MvcHtmlString`.

Comment: Thanks. Also, thanks to all the responses. @p.s.w.g's answer was most complete in that it gave sound reasoning for declaring in my model (plus, if I use this 100 times, it's technically less code/characters). +1 to all the other good suggestions.

Comment: @JoeEnos true, but FWIW, you probably want to separate your view models from your data models anyway.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Razor, strings are HTML-encoded by default - you'll need to use `Html.Raw` to turn off the encoding:

```
@Html.Raw(x.TextNotIncluded)
```

In the ASPX engine, you would use `<%= %>`

```
<%= x.TextNotIncluded %> - this gives you the raw text
<%: x.TextNotIncluded %> - this HTML-encodes your text - you don't want this.
```

Answer (score 4):

To output raw HTML, use the [`Raw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) HTML helper:

```
@Html.Raw(TextNotIncluded)
```

This helper doesn't HTML encode the input, so be careful when using it.

Comment: +1 on the "be careful" part - raw HTML opens you up to possible attacks if the text is user-generated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to HTML encode the string. Most are recommending the MVC approach, but I would make it more independent of the presentation layer.

```
public string TextNotIncluded { 
    get { 
        return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("which is <u>not</u> included in the Quote"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This is backward. This would make the property's value `which is &lt;u&gt;not&lt;/u&gt; included`, so if you tried to put that on the page, you'd either see it double-encoded or as plain text, but you'd never see it was underlined text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
@Html.Raw(Model.TextNotIncluded)
```

or

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.TextNotIncluded)
```

in your view.
But it would be better to alter the return type of the property:

```
public MvcHtmlString TextNotIncluded
{
    get
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("which is <u>not</u> included in the Quote");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Same answer as @p.s.w.g basically, but his came first.